# How to Accumulate Historic Data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

We have a situation were a table full data is replaced during data refresh. We would like to compare the refreshed data with the previous data that it held.

One option that I thought of was to clone the table and then refresh the original table. However, refreshing the original table also refreshes the data in the clone.

Is there any other way that the original table is refreshed without refreshing the clone/copy table?

Other solution I thought was to use SSAS and create two tables on the top of the source. This way each table can be processed individually.

However, in this situation, SSAS is not an option so is it possible to do this within Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI is not really suited to this purpose and accumulating historic data is best done upstream in your DB or data warehouse.

However, there are options out there using dataflows which you can read about here although it is not a recommended pattern: https://data-azure.com/2021/10/25/dataflows-to-store-as-historical-data/